# figure not shown or causes undefined control sequence

Tags: floats, pdftex, compiling

I am using TexStudio but when I tried to compile my file with pdflatex I had the same issues. Only one of my figures is not displayed in the pdf file. All figures are .png. I have tried to switch to .pdf, but it doesn't make a difference. Then I moved the figure  a section up, no difference.

Moving  few sections up caused an error while compiling:"Undefined control sequence" on my \todo{ something } command. The weird part: it complains only for a few of the  \todo commands after the included figure, not all of them, and the picture is displayed.

I'm not even sure what information to provide, because this could be a bug, a package issue and I'm not even sure if I can reproduce it with other files. I have tried to google this bahaviour without success, and hope that someone can help me.

EDIT: these are the error messages on one of the \todo commands

`! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tally@float \expandafter {\@captype 
                                                  }
l.225 ...hown in \todo{ add plot}
                                                  .
?`

`! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \ftype@ 
l.225 ...hown in \todo{ add plot}
                                                  .
?`

`! Extra \endcsname.
\tally@float ...ame ftype@#1\endcsname \endcsname 
                                                  \@ifnotrelax \@tempa {\@if...
l.225 ...hown in \todo{ add plot}
                                                  .
?`

When the figure is at the right place, but not displayed, I can't find anything in the log files close to it's lines.

Comment: It's more likely to be an error in your file than a package bug. start by showing the full error message from the log from `!` to `?` Add it to  a code section in the question, so that lines endings are preserved in the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a package issue, no idea why but commenting out the todonotes package solved everything.

```
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
```